# how to get the value of inner html into c# codebehind on page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, code-behind

Hi i have this code in java script i need the value of ip in the Code behind

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://www.telize.com/jsonip?callback=DisplayIP";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    };
    function DisplayIP(response) {
        **document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;**

    }
```

Comment: Make `ipaddress` a server control, and read the ip from it

Comment: You know you get the IP-address in codebehind from the client without scripts like these? See Request.ServerVariables

Comment: make a hiddent field having name attribute 'hdnIpAddress' or any you like and on server side check Request.Params["hdnIpAddress"]

Comment: hey guys i need the ip of the client machine.i use this javascript on client browser but .cannot get in the page load .not the click event

Answer (score 1):

You can set hidden field in your JavaScript. Create a field in your ASP code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ipHidden" runat="server" />
```

In your JavaScript add this:

```
    function DisplayIP(response) {
        document.getElementById("ipaddress").innerHTML = "Your IP Address is " + response.ip;
        document.getElementById("ipHidden").value = response.ip;
    }
```

In C#:

```
string clientIP = ipHidden.value;
```

Comment: i cannot get the value on code behind .i need in on page load

Answer (score 1):

you cannot get IP field on server side because the your java script will execute after your code behind finishes execution. you will be able to get it only when page finishes its rendering